# 64-bit Java not working

Tags: windows, java, 64-bit

I have been trying `java -d64`, but get `Error: This Java instances does not support a 64-bit JVM. Please install the desired version.` 
I know I installed the 64-bit version, and when I go to Control Panel -> Programs and Features, I have "Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 212 (64-bit)". Any idea as to why this is?

Comment: `java -d64` is not a valid option. If you are executing an 64bit Java than it automatically runs as 64bit (there is no other possibility). If the standard Java version is not 64bit then you may have an old Java version lying around that has no (uni)installer. Execute `which java.exe` to see where it is installed and delete the whole installation directory.

Comment: Is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` listed on your environment path?

Comment: My JAVA_HOME is pointing to the supposed 64-bit version.

Comment: @barlop Of course I looked it up - nothing worked.

Comment: @formicaman - You will need to be more detailed in your descriptions of the problem, "nothing worked", does not tell us what you tried.  Instead of replying to comments you should clarify your question by editing it.

Comment: The JAVA_HOME variable is irrelevant for starting Java. Which Java version is started is determined by `PATH` environment variable (unless you use Oracle Java). Usually only Java programs that need a Java compiler use `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: @formicaman you should have included in your question the things you tried. That way people suggesting things don't suggest things you tried

Answer (score -1):

First, you should run `where java` or `java -version` to make sure you are running what you think you are. If you aren't, get the path to the version folder of the java version you are trying to run and run this:

```
C:\Users\YourName>C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\<folder with version\bin\java.exe <args>
```

Or you could do this:

```
path = %path%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\<version>\bin
```

For example with a specific JDK version:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin\java.exe -jar RunMe.jar
```

This will also maintain directory, so if you run either of these commands, this will act like the executable is copied to the folder you are running it from.

Comment: No Way. You are confused. Look at the error he gets it is nothing to do with a path. And there's also no reason for you to be giving an example with a jar file either.

Comment: No. IF he is getting a 64-bit instance error, that means that the instance he is running does not support 64-bit. My answer is a way to specifically run an instance that does support 64-bit. And the -jar was just an example to show that it still functions the same.

Comment: If that's the case (and it may be), then his error is that he isn't running the one he installed. So what he should do is `where java` and verify that he is running the one he thinks he is running   he isn't, then you should tell him that.

Comment: Ok, I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: `where java` (the where command is a windows command)

Comment: Yep. But this only gives the javapath location?

Comment: and `java -version`  (if you are a bit error prone then especially good to test out a thing first. Is quick to test)

Comment: No, I just tested this on my machine, and it gave me the x86 javapath exe and the regular javapath exe. Running java -version gives you java version info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108264/discussion-between-tcoder-and-barlop).